# How to load files with different names to different tables in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have two files that are named like this:
CustomerReport(08022021-08032021)
ComparingReport(08022021-08032021)
I need to load the CustomerReport to a table and the ComparingReport to another table.
I tried for each loop container but I cant think of how the expression will be to pickup the file.
Im thinking of something like Customer*.csv where the * acts like a wild card but that didnt work. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here key of the answer is to use `Foreach Loop` and `Conditional Split`.

Don't pay attention on errors, because I don't have your CSV files and tables in DB!

1. Create a new variable `FileName` - string data type

[image]

2. Add `foreach loop` and set like on screenshot

Collection Tab:

[image]

Variable Mappings Tab:

[image]

3. Add `Data Flow Task` into `Foreach Loop` container
4. Drag elements from toolbox like on a image

[image]

5. `Flat File Source` connect to one of your CSV file using `Flat File Connection Manager` and on connection manager, in properties > expressions, set for `ConnectionString` a variable `FileName`
6. Set `Conditional Split` like on a image

Expression for `Customer` is:

```
LEFT(
SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName],FINDSTRING((@[User::FileName]),"Customer",1),100),
FINDSTRING(SUBSTRING(@[User::FileName],FINDSTRING((@[User::FileName]),"Customer",1),100),"Report",1) - 1
) == "Customer"
```

[image]

7. Connect `Conditional Split` to `OLE DB Destination's`

---

**NOTE:** I can't run package as I said on top of this answer, Pay attention to `Conditional Split`, but this is the way how you need to find if part of a string is into whole string.

Comment: This is a great method, Thank you!
its picking the file name but for somereason it fails right after that with this error. 
[Conditional Split [2]] Error: The start index 0 is not valid for function "SUBSTRING". The start index value must be an integer greater than 0. Start index is one-based, not zero-based.
its picking the file but the package is failing right after it. is there anyway to go around this?

Comment: Try with a breakpoint to pause executing package when foreach pick file name (breakpoint on conditional split pre-execution). See if variable `FullName` is something like D:\Your\Path\To\Folder\File.csv. If this is a case, then my expression will work. Send me value of `FullName` variable just before conditional split and I will try to modify expressions. And like I said, this is just logic how you should solve your problem.

Comment: @Sam332 Please accept my answer if it is the right solution.